# Is it possible to cancel PerformSelector on multiple objects?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a few classes that can call performSelector:afterDelay.

In some circumstances I want to cancel any and all of them.

However all the cancelPerformSelector type methods take a target, thus it would seem there is no way to cancel everything in one go (as there are different targets)?

Unless specifying nil as the target will cancel everything?

Or could the target be specified as [NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] to cancel everything such as

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]]
```

Comment: You should keep an array of all targets that can be cancelled, and then loop through all of them to cancel to the request.

Comment: Why won't the above code work? It should in theory right?

Comment: I do not see it [documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) anywhere that passing `nil` or an `NSRunLoop` will cancel all previous request, so there is no reason to believe that it will work in theory.

Comment: But its documented that calling it on the target will cancel all requests for that target, and aren't the perfromSelector's "hanging off" the run loop? I think its worth an experiment to see if it works.

Comment: The "target" is the object the selector will be called on, not the run loop that will initiate that call. Even if your experiment works if it is undocumented then relying on it would be ill advised.

Comment: How about if the objects calling performSelector are inheriting from a base class and the base class is specified as the target?

Comment: The answer is NO, the target has to be the object (same address) as the object you called it on. The solution I recommended for storing them in an array is your best option for this. As CRD said, anything outside of passing the target is undocumented behavior. If you want to try and go outside of that you are responsible for all [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) that you unleash.

Comment: Are those classes some custom objects? If they are you could solve this problem very quickly by overriding performSelector:afterDelay: and few other details, using some external array as others suggested.

Comment: The ability to cancel all would be highly dangerous anyway, as it could screw up any code that isn't yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a view controller declared similar to the following:

```
@interface CarViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong) id myObject;

@end
```

Also assuming you've registered the request for perform selector with the `myObject` instance somewhere in your implementation like the code below:

```
[self.myObject performSelector:@selector(someSelector) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
```

For sake of argument, you want your view controller to cancel all the previous perform requests before it is unloaded from memory, your `-viewWillUnload` message would look like:

```
- (void)viewWillUnload {
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self.myObject]
}
```

This would cancel all the perform requests registered for that particular instance. As Joe pointed out, if you are not keeping a strong reference to your objects by yourself and you're storing those objects in a `NSArray`, you need to iterate that array and call `+cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:` for each element of the array, or even `NSArray`'s `-enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:`:

```
- (void)viewWillUnload {
    [myArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:obj];
    }];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 Thanks, for the detailed explanation. You should not try to force an API to do something that it was not designed to do. And often times this is overcome by keeping track of objects and iterating over them. I find it amazing what people are willing to do to avoid iteration.